# XPath: found last element with criteria

Tags: xml, xpath

this xpath-Statement extract the first value from Attribut Adressen/Adresse/NUMMER

```
   //Adressen/Adresse/NUMMER[../TYP="P"]
```

Response: 20171129100600

But I try to get the **last** value from the Property Adressen/Adresse/NUMMER
with  Adressen/Adresse/TYP="P"

I don't know how, please help me

best regards

Michael

this is my XML

```
<Adressen>
   <Adresse>
      <HDLNR>111MK001</HDLNR>
      <FILNR>0001</FILNR>
      <USERNR>1</USERNR>
      <AUFART>K</AUFART>
      <AUFTRKENN>U</AUFTRKENN>
      <AUFTRNR>-1</AUFTRNR>
      <FNR>1</FNR>
      <ART>K</ART>
      <FUNC>2</FUNC>
      <NUMMER>20171129100600</NUMMER>
      <ADRFIL>0001</ADRFIL>
      <TYP>P</TYP>
   </Adresse>
         <Adresse>
      <HDLNR>111MK001</HDLNR>
      <FILNR>0001</FILNR>
      <USERNR>1</USERNR>
      <AUFART>K</AUFART>
      <AUFTRKENN>U</AUFTRKENN>
      <AUFTRNR>-1</AUFTRNR>
      <FNR>1</FNR>
      <ART>K</ART>
      <FUNC>2</FUNC>
      <NUMMER>20171129104643</NUMMER>
      <ADRFIL>0001</ADRFIL>
      <TYP>P</TYP>
           </Adresse>
         <Adresse>
      <HDLNR>111MK001</HDLNR>
      <FILNR>0001</FILNR>
      <USERNR>1</USERNR>
      <AUFART>K</AUFART>
      <AUFTRKENN>U</AUFTRKENN>
      <AUFTRNR>-1</AUFTRNR>
      <FNR>1</FNR>
      <ART>K</ART>
      <FUNC>2</FUNC>
      <NUMMER>1511945910251</NUMMER>
           </Adresse>
   <Adresse>
      <HDLNR>111MK001</HDLNR>
      <FILNR>0001</FILNR>
      <USERNR>1</USERNR>
      <AUFART>K</AUFART>
      <AUFTRKENN>U</AUFTRKENN>
      <AUFTRNR>-1</AUFTRNR>
      <FNR>1</FNR>
      <ART>K</ART>
      <FUNC>2</FUNC>
      <NUMMER>4589458945</NUMMER>
      <ADRFIL>0001</ADRFIL>
      <TYP>F</TYP>
            </Adresse>
</Adressen>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `last()` function to get the last item of collection

```
(//Adressen/Adresse[TYP="P"]/NUMMER)[last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(//Adressen/Adresse/NUMMER[following-sibling::TYP="P"])[last()]
```

Comment: Can you add more of an explanation of what that change does/why it works?